# Does Arial support Chinese characters?

Tags: css, utf-8, fonts

Is that right to say that Arial doesn't support Chinese characters?

There are a few Chinese websites that uses font-family: Arial. However that doesn't mean that the Chinese characters are in Arial. The English characters will be displayed in Arial and the Chinese characters will ignore Arial and use the default Chinese character on a PC which is Simsun.

Am I right?

A quick Character Map check on Arial also doesn't reveal Chinese characters in the font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arial does not have any Chinese characters; see [MS description of Arial](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1705), which lists the writing systems supported. When a page declares `font-family: Arial` and contains Chinese characters, those characters will be taken from the browser’s default font, which is usually SimSun on Windows systems, or (if not found there) from another font in the system, using a browser-dependent method of scanning through fonts.